# Three.js change light intensity dynamically

Tags: javascript, three.js

Is there a way that i have not seen to change the light intensity of directional lights on the fly? Or even ambient light?

```
ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff);
scene.add(ambientLight);            

directionalLightL = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, dLight, 0);
directionalLightL.position.set(dlpX, dlpY, dlpZ);
scene.add(directionalLightL);
```

So that is done initially to render, but how can i change just one specific lights intensity afterwards? Remove/re-add the light? Find it in the dom and change it? Something in the API i have not noticed?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To change the intensity for a `DirectionalLight`, `SpotLight`, `PointLight`, or `AmbientLight`, you just set it:

```
light.intensity = 0.5;
```

You can change the light color like so:

```
light.color.setHex( 0xff0000 );
```

See `Color.js` for other ways to set a color.

three.js r.74